# Cannot echo variable in text jQuery Easy UI

Tags: php, jquery-easyui

Why I cant set value with echo variable in text form jquery eui?

```
<input type="text" name="text1" class="easyui-validatebox" value="<? echo $varPhp; ?>" size="53"/></td>
```

My php function like this..

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT MAX(kode_barang) as maxID FROM tb_barang";
        $hasil = mysql_query($query);
        $data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
        $idMax = $data['maxID'];
        $noUrut = (int) substr($idMax, 1, 4);
        $noUrut++;
        $varPhp = "B" . sprintf("%04s", $noUrut);
        ?>
```

Anyone can help me?

Question Closed.. :) i pass the process and create in model.

Answer (score 1):

May be your php version doesnt support the use of  short tags.Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) .And try this

```
<input type="text" name="text1" class="easyui-validatebox" value="<?php echo $varPhp; ?>" size="53"/>
```

Comment: what do u mean short tag User016?

Comment: instead of using php tag like this  `<?php ?>` you can use `<? ?>` this also if your php version supports short hand and that is called as short tag.And check the documentation link i provided in the answer.

Comment: Short tag in the sense - you don't have <?php every time instead you could do <?

Comment: I try your suggest to add <?php and try in higher version the result doesnt not show..

Comment: Then check whether any value is in `$varPhp` using `var_dump($varPhp);`

Comment: the variable not empty.. when i echo var_dump($varPhp) between <td> </td> the result are show string(5) B0001..

Comment: Let me ask what is the extension of your file.? is it .php

Comment: i think the problem in set value text.. cause when i try manual value="test" the text is not show the value..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php echo $varPhp; ?>
```

Comment: well, shorttag availability depends on PHP version.

Comment: Check what is the value of $varPhp. Does it really have value?

Comment: I try in higher php version. the error like this. Undefined variable: newID. i try manual value="test" the value are not show..

Comment: It clearly means in your php code, you have not defined this variable. Post the complete code snippet.\

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your variable is empty.

To ensure that, use var_dump to dump it.

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="text1" class="easyui-validatebox" value="<?php var_dump($varPhp); ?>" size="53"/>
```

Comment: still not work user1915746. when i create echo between <td> <?php var_dump($varPhp); ?> </td> the result are show.. the result string(5) B0001.

Comment: And if you do my suggestion (within the input element)? What do you see? Empty textbox? If yes, have a view at source code (html) which is transmitted from your server to the browser. Press Ctrl+U in Firefox. Whats written here?

Comment: Looks good so far. Your variable is not empty since you get "string(5) B0001." Please check the row html and ensure that the varibale is set BEFORE you try to output it.